# Repeat numbers to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have data set like this :

```
City          Money   Code       Quantity
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3   
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3         
London        1.96    54645641    3       
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4 
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Madrid        200     158484      4         
Denver        56.7    494681818   1
```

and i would like to add a number to each line by repeated City's block by a maximum of Quantity's value , i mean to get this :

```
City          Money   Code       Quantity result
London        1.96    54645641    3         1
London        1.96    54645641    3         2
London        1.96    54645641    3         3
London        1.96    54645641    3         1
London        1.96    54645641    3         2
London        1.96    54645641    3         3
Madrid        200     158484      4         1
Madrid        200     158484      4         2
Madrid        200     158484      4         3
Madrid        200     158484      4         4
Madrid        200     158484      4         1
Madrid        200     158484      4         2
Madrid        200     158484      4         3
Madrid        200     158484      4         4
Denver        56.7    494681818   1         1
```

COUNTIF function doesnt give me the expected result.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: It is unclear what the logic of your desired result. What Formula did your try, exactly? and how does it fail to achieve what you want?

Comment: i used the formula COUNTIF to increment numbers but i got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF4Kz.png

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I had answered this question back on StackOverflow with: `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` But then the OP decided to change the parameters of the question after I answered without asking a new one, so I deleted my answer there.  Had they rolled the question back to the prior version and accepted my answer I would have gladly answered the new question when it was asked with the new parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559665/add-numbers-to-rows-by-block-with-excel-vba/69559701?noredirect=1#comment122953593_69559701

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for your answer. i realized i get wrong with the data that is why i edited the topic with new parameters

Comment: The proper etiquette is to accept the answer that answered the question as it was and then ask a new question.  When you edit the question after you get an answer it opens up the existing answer to down votes.  What you should do, especially now that you have asked the new question here, is revert the old question back to the original so I can undelete my answer that answered that question.

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay, I just revert the old question back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for VBA, but the formula is fairly simple.

Use MOD with COUNTIF and a variable range:

```
=MOD(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1,D2)+1
```

COUNTIF will return the count as it goes down.  MOD then returns the remainder.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your precious help